# Can I say "fixed costs-intensive program"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, hyphenation, phrase-usage

Is the term "fixed costs-intensive program" correct? For example, can I write the following sentence?

> The lack of financial resources discouraged the firm to start a fixed costs-intensive marketing program.

Answer (score 1):

In North America, it would probably be *cost-intensive*, while in UK, the extra *s* seems to be used in analogous words. But the rest of the sentence needs work, too. With a negative verb such as *discouraged*, the preposition *from* (followed by a gerund) is grammatical,
*discouraged the firm from starting a fixed cost-intensive ...*, whereas *to start* doesn't sound right, and could be confusing.

And you should check whether local practice (practise?) is to use *programme* or *program*, not to mention *marketting* or *marketing*.